# how to fire touchesBegan & touchesMoved event on UIImageView

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad

I wants to change images when user move his figure on UIImageView But touchesBegan & touchesMoved events are not fired. Please help me.

Comment: did you enable the Userinteraction for the UIImageView?

Comment: yes i have enabled it..

Comment: In subclassed UIImageView?

Comment: why don't you show us your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set userInteractionEnabled to YES on all of the superviews too.

Answer (score 0):

Add UITapGestureRecognizer to UIImageView